# how do i connect oracle apex to send sms using a sms gateway?

Tags: sms-gateway, oracle-apex

I'm trying to develop an application in oracle apex that would send SMS to a mobile phone and I don't seem to know how to go about it.
I've read articles on other programming languages but don't know how to implement using apex.
I need instructions to guide me, willing to do any assignments I'd be given.

Comment: Are you asking how to send email from APEX?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just [send them as email](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/APEX_FAQ#How_does_one_send_E-mail_from_APEX.3F)?

You can [send email to SMS gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway#Use_with_email_clients) and it will be received as a text message. You will need to know the address used by your recipient's carrier, but there are various sources listing each carrier's address and message format, such as [this](http://www.ukrainecalling.com/email-to-text.aspx).

For example, to send to a number typically expressed in the USA as 987-555-0100, you would email 9875550100@SMS-gateway.

Comment: ok, 10ks a lot...i think i should try that too...but i tried another way...got a sample code from patrick wolf's blog and granted an execute statement to my user...alternatively, i got a sms gateway and configured it manually to pick messages from my msgout table...thanks a lot for your help

Comment: can you please share the patrick wolf's blog and the sms gateway you configured?